# Is there a real version of the non-commutative Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, spherical-harmonics

In David Applebaum's "Probability on Compact Lie Groups", ch.2 page 36, we have the following definition of the non-commutative Fourier transform where $G$ is e.g. a compact Lie group, $f \in L^1(G; \mathbb{C})$ and $\pi$ is a complex unitary irrep of $G$:

$$
\widehat{f}(\pi) := \int_G \pi(g^{-1}) f(g) dg
$$

> **Question:**  Analogous to how we may define the sine and cosine series instead of the complex Fourier series for a periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$, is there a definition of non-commutative Fourier transform (on compact Lie groups is sufficient) in terms of only real-valued functions and representations on real vector spaces?

If it simplifies things, I really only care about the case $G=SO(3)$ and real-valued functions $L^1(SO(3); \mathbb{R})$.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide :)

Comment: Ask Dave, he's a nice guy!

Comment: In the convolution algebra $L^1(G, \mathbb{C})$ you have a nonstandard involution $\sigma$ given by $f \mapsto f^\ast$. Your real algebra is the fixed point algebra of that involution. Try to express $\sigma$ as a combination of a permutation of irreducible reps $[\pi] \mapsto [\pi^\sigma]$ (preserving the dimension $d_\pi$) and an antilinear involution $W_{\pi}: M_{d_\pi} \to M_{d_{\pi^\sigma}}$. Your trigonometric basis will be given by the images of elements under $(1 + \sigma)/2$ and $(1 - \sigma)/2 i$.

Comment: If i recall correctly the irreducible representations of $G = SO(3)$ are given by $G$ acting of homogeneous polynomials of degree $m$ on the sphere. Therefore, there's at most one representation of any given degree, up to unitary eq, and the permutation $[\pi] \mapsto [\pi^\sigma]$ is the identity. To get the involution $M_{d_\pi} \to M_{d_\pi}$ just express the conjugation over the spaces of homogeneous harmonic polynomials in the sphere and conjugate by it.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez If you can elaborate on how to do that to get an actual real fourier transform, I'd be happy to accept that answer!